# How to run a test in LSP with a key binding?

Tags: lsp, lsp-ui

In `lsp-ui-mode`, `test` appears as a clickable UI element.

Is there a keybinding to run a test without using the mouse?

Comment: What does `C-h k` tell you that the mouse click is bound to?

Comment: It gives a complex LSP command for the specific file I'm inside

Comment: That's not enough info for me to tell you anything other than "search the lisp code for other things which are running that command".  Failing that, I expect someone familiar with this package will have an answer.

Comment: Give a clue ... Add a screenshot or ateast specify which language or framework you are using to run unit tests.  Don't assume that everyone uses `lsp`, so give enough context to make sure that the people trying to help you have an enough context to help you right away.  Usually buttons are .. With cursor on the `test` string, do `M-x describe-text-properties` and paste the result here and with cursor on the `test` string do `C-h k` followed by `Left Mouse Click` and report what it says